# Knapsack using backtracking

Tags: java

I'm having trouble on where to call the function recursively. If i place it inside the else condition it will not check for other elements while the function is returning. If i place it outside the else it will execute one time while returning back and does not execute for other elements while returning.
How should i change the code so that it will check for every element while backtracking? (weights and profits array are public arrays)
Thanks in advance.

```
private static int calculateMaxProfit(int n, int maxprofit,int weight) 
{
    if(weight+weights[i]>maxweight)
    {
        i++;
        if(i<n)
            return calculateMaxProfit(n,maxprofit,weight);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        weight+=weights[i];
        maxprofit+=profits[i];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    static int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; } 
  

    static int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int profits[], int n) 
    { 
        // Base Case 
        if (n == 0 || W == 0) 
            return 0; 

        if (wt[n - 1] > W) 
            return knapSack(W, wt, profits, n - 1); 
  
   
            return max(profits[n - 1] + knapSack(W - wt[n - 1], wt, profits, n - 1), 
                       knapSack(W, wt, profits, n - 1)); 
    }
```